# Compress Image Size without affecting its dimensions asp vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, image, compression

I am retrieving an image from the database through ashx, the webpage could only be viewed through our intranet, but on some users, the image loading takes really long. So I was thinking maybe compressing the image size would lessen the loading time, I should also maintain the image dimensions which is 400 by 441.What is the possible way to compress the image size? It is in jpeg format.

Comment: Hi Ley47. Have you used a tool like firebug to confirm that it is the images causing the problem? A tool like firebug can help you to isolate what the actual problem is:     http://www.kevinleary.net/testing-page-load-speed-with-firebug/

Comment: I haven't yet but I'll try it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use GDI+ to compress the image.  Check out [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882583.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) on MSDN.

Note that there's an overload for both the contructor and Save method of Bitmap that can take a Stream instead of a file path.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it, I am just retrieving the pictures and I can't do any revisions on it's saving process. Is there a possible way of compression after retrieval?

Comment: This method will still work without having to "save" the image to disk or a database.  You can retrieve the image from the database, modify it in memory and write it to the output stream. There's an in-depth discussion of this technique here: http://www.devproconnections.com/article/aspnet2/serving-images-on-the-web-122480